# Sync tables option not available in local install of CartoDB

Tags: carto

I've got a production version of CartoDB running locally, but when I try and create a table based on a spreadsheet hosted on Dropbox I don't get the option to keep the data in sync, instead I get upgrade your account.

What do I need to do to resolve this?

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can enable them in the interface for all the users in your local install by updating the `sync_tables_enabled` row on the `users` table:

`UPDATE users SET sync_tables_enabled = 1;`

However, sync tables also require a script to be ran every 15 minutes, which will enqueue pending synchronizations:

`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake cartodb:sync_tables`

I've filed two tickets for this to get properly documented:

https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/issues/1359
https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/issues/1358